# Impementation of QListView with MouseDoubleClick Event

Tags: qt, qlistview

I am intended to implement an QListView, which will be showing a frame when I will double press my mousebutton on each delegate. With my very basic programming skill I cann't do it. Here below is my code:

```
void MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
{

if (obj == ui->listView->viewport() && event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonDblClick)
{
    int row = getListViewRow();
    qDebug() << "Double Clicked on Row: " << row << endl;
    mFrame->setGeometry(700,500,150,150);
    mFrame->show();  }}
```

Inside my constructor I also have added this below line:

```
qApp->installEventFilter(this);
```

So please correct me to achieve the goal. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is quite simple: If you install an event-filter, you need to install it on the object whos events you want to filter:

```
ui->listView->viewport()->installEventFilter(this);
```

Comment: Thanks @Felix! If I have got you correctly then you want to mean that I have to add this line into the constructor too. But I am having the following error. 

 error: C2555: 'MainWindow::eventFilter': overriding virtual function return type differs and is not covariant from 'QObject::eventFilter'

Comment: Your event-filter must return a bool whether it actually filtered the event or not: `bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)`. If you return true, Qt will stop handling the event.

Comment: A big thanks @Felix! Its working. Now I am going to update the code. Can you suggest me any document to read on for my better understanding with QEvent?